# How to add conditions in a reactive WebFlux .filter() flow in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I want to create a conditional `WebFilter` that executes one logic if `ServerWebExchangeMatcher` matches, and another logic if it does not match.

The following already works for a "positive" match, by using `.filter(..::isMatch)`. But how could I add a `.orElse()` method here into the flow?

```
class PathFilter implements org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter {
    private ServerWebExchangeMatcher paths;
    
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        //TODO how to add a "no-match" execution?
        return this.paths.matches(exchange)
                    .filter(ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult::isMatch)
                    .flatMap(...)
                    .then();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure you can easily add orElse to a chain, and I think it would quickly become unmaintainable as it branches off. Personally I would just flatMap with a method that has a primitive if/else and returns whichever flow you want instead of filter

Answer (score 2):

So what @123 probably means is the following:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    return this.paths.matches(exchange)
                .flatMap((matchResult) ->
                        matchResult.isMatch()
                                ? customLogic(exchange, chain)
                                : chain.filter(exchange)) //continue normal flow
                .then();
}
```

Which works, but I'd still be interested if there is a possibility to delegate a "negative-match" outcome directly inside the flow, maybe with `switchIfEmpty()` or similar.

Comment: There is no such feature, reactive programming is not optionals. If else statements are still a thing.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution for above one is "switchIfEmpty()" can be added in case filter condition become false. Please let me know if you fave any further question on this.

```
class PathFilter implements org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter {
    private ServerWebExchangeMatcher paths;
    
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        //TODO how to add a "no-match" execution?
        return this.paths.matches(exchange)
                    .filter(ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult::isMatch)
                    .flatMap(...)
                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> doSomethingElse()));
    }
}
```